# Discord.py Invoking a Command with *Args on Command Error

Tags: python, discord.py

When I get an quotation mark error, I'm trying to run the command again by fixing the quotation marks that are causing the error. But I can't get to pass arguments correctly whether I used get_command() with and without callback(), or invoke(). I tried to pass arguments manually but it didn't work. I receive no member argument error or there's no member "'m' error depending on the method I use and the message that invokes the command. I can't seem to pass arguments appropriately.

Example:
?verify @user I’m a good member, I want to be verified.

```
@bot.command()  
async def verify(ctx,member : discord.Member,*args):
  member_name = member.name + '#' + member.discriminator
  author_name = ctx.author.name + '#' + ctx.author.discriminator
  avatar = member.avatar_url    
  create_date = member.created_at
  join_date = member.joined_at
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Verified")

  comment = ''
  for arg in args:
      comment = comment + " " + arg

  Verify command code continues...

@verify.error
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.UnexpectedQuoteError):
      if hasattr(ctx, 'coerced_quotes'):
          return
      if error.quote in ("’", "‘", '”', '‟'):
          ctx.message.content = ctx.message.content.replace("’", "'")
          ctx.message.content = ctx.message.content.replace("‘", "'")
          ctx.message.content = ctx.message.content.replace("”", '"')
          ctx.message.content = ctx.message.content.replace("‟", '"')
          ctx.coerced_quotes = True
          // await bot.invoke(ctx)
          // await bot.get_command('verify').callback(ctx)
```

Comment: Hey Magnus, welcome to Stack! What do you mean by it "didn't work"? What are you expecting to happen? Are you getting any errors when using your code?

Comment: When I get an quotation mark error, I'm trying to run the command again by fixing the quotation marks that are causing the error. Still, I receive no member argument error or there's no member "'m' error depending on the method I use and the message that invokes the command. I can't seem to pass arguments appropriately. 

Example: ?verify @user I’m a good member, I want to be verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to make `args` a kwarg instead of making it a tuple of items. In discord.py `*, arg` makes it consume all of the string at once, so if you did `!verify @user I'm a super good person trust me!`, argument will become `I'm a super good person trust me!`. Once you get that, in your first line do the `str.replace()` for all of them and then continue your command normally, instead of trying to invoke it again in your `@verify.error`

also instead of `ctx.author.name + '#' + ctx.author.discriminator` you can just do `str(member)` which will give the same output `MemberName#Discriminator`

```py
@bot.command()  
async def verify(ctx: commands.Context, member : discord.Member, *, args: str = ""):
  args = args.replace("’", "'").replace("‘", "'").replace("”", '"').replace("‟", '"')
  member_name = str(member)
  author_name = str(ctx.author)
  avatar = member.avatar_url    
  create_date = member.created_at
  join_date = member.joined_at
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Verified")

  # Verify command code continues...
```

Comment: It works if a user adds a comment but that's optional. I had to make args optional for those who don't add any comment. I simply changed "args: str" to "args=''". I also had to change the comment block to simple "comment=args". Now it works perfect. Thanks for the answer. When you make it optional there I'll accept your answer

Comment: `: str` is basically a typehinting, you can ofc add `= ""` after that. Let me edit that